# Is it possible to load a module 'anywhere' in joomla with its javascript and css?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I already know great extensions like -modules anywhere-, however it doesn't load the javascript files nor the css ones. (At least in my case and as far as I've read).

Am I doing anything wrong ? Is it possible to load the modules in any article text, component, module with its js and css files ? if so, how ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same problem, and i created a normal html website, with javascript and css, and i used a wrapper link in joomla to embed that website to joomla site...but maybe there is a better solution too :)